# Boot partition on separate drive?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader, boot-partition

Have tried searching but drawing a blank, end up with pages of how to dual boot with windows.

I have a 250gb spinning disk alongside a 1.9TB PCIE Card SSD. Due to BIOS limitations I cannot boot from the PCIE card (hence addition of small spinning disk). Is it possible to have just boot partition on spinning disk with everything else installed on the SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm speaking about this screen (the picture is random, it's the first I've googled):

[image: partition selection example]

The answer depends on BIOS and actual kernel. First, try the simplest solution:

1. Select /dev/sd[spinning] for boot loader;
2. Create /dev/sd[SSD]1 partition and mount it as /;
3. Create /dev/sd[spinning]1 partition and mount it as /boot.

If this system fails to boot, you can try a more reliable solution:

1. Select /dev/sd[spinning] for boot loader;
2. Create /dev/sd[spinning]1 partition and mount it as /;
3. Create /dev/sd[SSD]1 partition and mount it as /usr;
4. Create /dev/sd[SSD]2 partition and mount it as /home;
5. Create /tmp, swap etc. partition the same way, as needed.

It'll not put literally everything on your SSD but most essential parts will be there.

But if initrd does not see the SSD, the boot will fail. It'll be another big question about tweaking the initrd.